# Display colorbox at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, colorbox

Is there a way to displat colorbox not in the middle of the page but at the top? By default the colorbox popup window is shown in the middle of the page but I want to set my own coordinates in order to display it a bit higher.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#colorbox{ top:0 !important; }

#colorbox{ top:100px !important; left:0 !important }
```

if you want to position it a bit highter from the center you could use

```
#colorbox{ margin-top:-30px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

for Dynamic change position

```
$(".example").colorbox({ top: 100, left: "50%" })
```